# Where is torrc file in TBB 3.5.1?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I install latest Tor browser bundle. I can open a browser.
But I need to add HidServAuth, but I don't know how to do it.
Is torrc file gone?

Comment: You are using an outdated version with known security issues. You should upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

`torrc` is located in the `Data/Tor` folder.

Please note that this location will [change with the next version](https://bugs.torproject.org/11641).